# Scrolling a WebKit2.Webkit window in GTK+3

Tags: python, language-agnostic, webkit, gtk, webkitgtk

How does one scroll a `webkit2gtk` widget?

In `webkitgtk` (aka. `webkit1`) you wrap your `WebView` in a `ScrolledWindow`, so can use its `vadjustment` property.

For `wekit2gtk`, this call on the `WebView` just returns `None`, and I see no other method to call.

As an explanation, I want to add touch support to `webkit2`. <strike>I have *hacked* my way into this by adding a transparent layer over the `WebView` widget</strike>¹, but now I'm detecting touches I seem unable to use them.

¹ A release that came out today has removed the need for the layer on-top. Nevertheless, I have touches and nothing I can do with them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The process separation in WebKit2 has some advantages, but it also makes many things more complex. I believe scrolling is one of those things: it happens in the web process because scrollbars are now handled by webkit, and not the Gtk widget. The same should hold for touch handling: it is partly done in the web process. Carlos Garcia Campos has written a [blog post](http://blogs.igalia.com/carlosgc/2013/09/10/webkit2gtk-web-process-extensions/) about using WebKitWebExtension to help in this. Note that the design has lots of implications on your code as well: Part of the code will be running in a totally different process.

The rest of the answer is not tested, please consider this more like an educated guess:

I believe the way to control scrolling is through the [DOM API](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitdomgtk/unstable/), more specifically `DOMDOMWindow.scroll*` functions. The complex part is getting a reference to the `DOMDOMWindow` -- You'll need to implement a `WebExtension` which will be running in the web process and will allow you to get notified when a `WebPage` is created. The `WebPage.get_dom_document()` call gives you a `DOMDocument` and `DOMDocument.get_default_view()` should then give you the `DOMDOMWindow` you need.

For the DOM API documentation, [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_Reference) is probably a better reference than the spartan  WebKit-GTK-DOM documentation.

If I was doing what you are trying to do, my first stop would be the #webkitgtk+ IRC channel on Freenode to check if the above really is a sane way to do what you want...

Answer (score 6):

You could run some javascript to scroll the page. The C API has the function `webkit_web_view_run_javascript()` so you could feed it some javascript like

```
window.scrollTo(500,0);
```

and the page should scroll.

Comment: This is by far the easiest solution in simple cases, since you do not need a webextension. Once things get more complicated and depends on the DOM tree - webextensions might be easier.

Comment: It works well. love this solution.